# Getting gdb to automatically load binary from core file

Tags: c++, gdb

Can I get gdb to automatically load the binary that's specified in the core file?

Given a core file I now usually do:

```
gdb -c corefile
GNU gdb 6.8
...
Core was generated by `/path/to/binary'
```

Then i copy-paste that and run:

```
gdb -c corefile /path/to/binary
```

It seems like an unnecessary two-step process and yet I don't seen an obvious way of doing it based on the man page. Am I missing something?

Answer (score 4):

You could just script it?

```
#!/bin/bash
gdb "`file "$1" | awk -F \' '{print $2}'`" "$1"
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I usually endup doing:

```
var=$(file corefile)
echo ${var##*from}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
gdc() {
    gdb -c "$1" "$(file "$1" | sed -r -e "s#.*execfn: '([^\']+)'.*#\1#")"
}
```

```
$ gdc corefile
```